# jQuery DatePicker doesn't appear asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm pretty new to the world of web development. I'm learning Asp.net MVC and I want to create a simple form element to let the user to select the date from a datepicker injected using jQuery. this what I had done so far,

I added a reference to jquery library to Layout file "_Layout.cshtml" like so:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the view I want to render which contain a textbox element generated using razor to insert date. A simple jquery script inserted before the form to inject datepicker but I couldn't select date after I run the form

```
 model MvcApplication3.Models.RegisterModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
</hgroup>

 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#BirthDate').datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "/images/calendar-icon.png",
              buttonImageOnly: true,
              buttonText: "Select date"
          });
      });
 </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
 }

 @section Scripts {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

This is the render HTMl :

[image: Rendered Hmtl]

whenever I click on BirthDate TextBox I got nothing

Comment: Does it work if you move the script containing the initialization after the `fieldset`? Also, remove the ` <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>`, the file is already loaded in the `head`.

Comment: Thank you sir for your suggestions, but it doesn't work either

Comment: That's very strange... What is it that doesn't actually work? Does the date picker pop up or not? Remove all the options and let the default settings to see if it appears.

Comment: Exactly, the date picker won't pop up

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML

Comment: I should have been a little clearer, the HTML markup.  :)  Also, remove the  link for `jquery-1.8.2.js` within your view, as you have added a link to this in your bundle.

Comment: I had already removed the link from the view and put it at the head of layout view, but nothing changed

Comment: Again, please post the actual HTML generated by your view....

Comment: I think it's a miss a little bit. I found an error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"

Comment: Why are you including both the development and release (.min) versions of all the jQuery files?  You should only use one at a time

Comment: I don't see your stylesheet reference for jquery ui?  Is it in the content/css  bundle?  Have you tried using the dev tools in Chrome, FF or IE to see if you have an error?

Comment: You have duplicate scripts all over the place! Most importantly after rendering all the scripts in the `<head>` tags, you then include `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>` after then. Since `jquery-ui` depends on `jquery`, because you reload it, you effectively wipe out `jquery-ui` (and all the other scripts that depend on `jquery`). Go to the [MVC Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) site and learn how to do this correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you have references all over the shop by the looks of it, I recommend you use the bundling that is included within MVC.  In your `BundleConfig` class check you have all your scripts loaded like this:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/dataTables.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

This is an example of how I have some loaded in a project.  Then within your `_Layout.cshtml` you place this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
   <body>
        @RenderBody()
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    </body>
```

You shouldn't need to load them manually like you have. This will keep all your scripts tidy.  If this doesn't work, load the browser console up and see just what files are being loaded, and see if any are being loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

Add the datepicker class to the textbox.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class="datepicker" })
```

then...

```
$(document).ready({
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Might also want that javascript to be at the bottom of your page, rather than up top.